# Get value from datetimepicker in code behind c#

Tags: c#, jquery

I'm doing some Sharepoint webparts and i'm trying to use a jquery datetimepicker, but i can't quite retrieve the value from the datetimepicker in the C# code behind. Here is my script :

```
   <input type="hidden" id="StartDateHiddenField" name="StartDateHiddenField" value=""/>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $(".datepicker1").datepicker({
                 changeMonth: true,
                 changeYear: true,
                 dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                 showButtonPanel: false,
                 onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                     $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
                     $('#StartDateHiddenField').val($(this).datepicker("getDate"));
                 }

             });
        });
    </script>
```

In code behind :

```
 var test = Page.Request.Form["StartDateHiddenField"];
 var startTime = DateTime.Parse(Page.Request.Form["StartDateHiddenField"]);
```

test value according to debugger is, for exemple :

> "Sat Jul 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)"

How can i get proper values from DateTime.Parse ?

Comment: something like `{1/1/0001 12:00:00AM}` or another format of DateTime ? I can't parse `Sat Jul 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200` into a DateTime instance"

Comment: `$(this).datepicker("getDate").toISOString()` I imagine would get it in a better format. You can do this because the getDate method returns a Date object. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString for details of the method.

Comment: That was it, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ADyson, a solution was to use `$(this).datepicker("getDate").toISOString()`